# SQL query to search for user tokens(skills)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-tokeninput

I am building a search system on my website that searches for user skills this skills are presented as tokens, the db table for user skills looks like this:

```
 id=> primary id(auto increment), 
user_id=> this is the user id,  
competence_nom=> this is the skill name, 
competence_id=> this is the skill parent id
```

So what I would like is when two skills(or more..) belong to one user the display goes like this:

```
user name + skill one + skill two
```

and not like this (what I'm achieving now)

```
user name +skill one
user name +skill two
```

I am using jQuery tokeninput plugin to pass the token data to server side, I pass the skill id to the server side, then on server side i explode the skill array given by jQuery tokeninput:

```
 $comps=explode(",", $_POST["competences"]);
```

then i put this in a foreach loop:

```
 foreach($comps as $i=>$v){  


}
```

and this is where i get the bad output:

```
user name +skill one
    user name +skill two
```

Comment: I don't think that a single mysql query would give you the results in the desired format. You need to fetch the data and restructure it in your php code.

Comment: yes, i'm trying to do it by populating arrays from sql queries but i still can't succeed.

Comment: What query are you using at the moment?

Comment: lot of incongruent stuff in this query but it gives me the repeated pattern:

`$a=$db->query("SELECT * FROM  competences, competences_user, users WHERE users.id=user_id AND ".$_comps."=competence_id  AND  ".$_comps."=c_id   AND user_id!=0  GROUP BY c_id "); `

(this query inside the foreach)

Answer (score 0):

As I currently understand it, this is a problem with your data model.

The central questions are what use cases your data model hast to support and, as part of that, how efficient the underlying queries have to be.

If you have a very limited set of skills and need a very high performance, you might want to go for a solution where a skill set is really represented as a bit set.

If clear user interface and clear data model are main objectives and performance is potentially of secondary importance, the approach that comes to one's mind is having a relational data model with person core data in one table, and assigned skills in a second table, like so:

```
TABLE person
id: (auto increment)
name: (or split into first name etc)
email: (etc, you get the idea)

TABLE skill
id: (auto increment)
description:

TABLE personskill
personid: (reference to person.id)
skillid: (reference to skill.id)
```

Then, with relational database queries, the system will answer the question which skills are assigned to which person.

```
SELECT skillid FROM personskill WHERE personid = (id of person you're looking at)
```

Comment: i have the exact table scheme you posted, my problem comes from the php foreach i do server side wich repeats the data:  `user name +skill one
user name +skill two`

Comment: @user7832 Okay then I was misled by the fact that you appeared to have the skill name and an autoincrement id in the "personskill" table, for which I cannot see a reason. So I wouldn't say that you have the "exact" table scheme I suggest.

Comment: oh sorry, yes i have an autoincrement id in the "personskill" table because people can add skills dynamically(so the skill gets added to the main skill table but also as a skill for the particular user)

Comment: @user7832 In what way is the fact that users can add skills dynamically a reason for having an auto-incremented id in a table which simply associates a skill to a person? Also, why the replication of the name?

Comment: well having or not an AI would not affect anything, it's verbose maybe. replication of name is verbose also but i dont think this alters the way i could do a querie.

Comment: @user7832 Fine. I've never achieved happiness by having to maintain redundant data in a relational data model consistently. But, of course, your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GROUP_CONCAT command of mysql.

Here is the link to details of this command

http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php

Hope this helps.

Thanks.